# How do I make a full screen scrolling messagebox or window?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, windows-mobile, mobile

First let me start of saying I know absolutely nothing about c++ and I am really just more interested in getting this to work then learning c++(I got enough on my plate to learn).

So basically I am trying to make a terms of service for my windows mobile 6 professional application but it seems I need to use c++ to do it. After hours of searching I found a solution but it developed for windows mobile standard.

So they somehow used c++ to make a message box and on standard devices(ie non touch screen phones) the message box can have like scrolling. For some reason this is not the case with professional devices(touch screen devices).

So my message box goes off the page and you can never accept or decline the terms. So your stuck and on the screen forever till you do some sort of soft restart.

http://www.mobilepractices.com/2008/10/setupdll-sample-and-walkthrough-terms.html

The above link is the tutorial but here is the actual file that seems to display the message.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ce_setup.h"

// This is a variable containing the text to be displayed
// in the Terms & Conditions dialog

TCHAR Message[] = _T("TERMS & CONDITIONS\r\n ")
             _T("Selecting YES you're accepting our terms & conditions.\r\n")
    _T("This is just a sample application.\r\n")
    _T("From http://www.mobilepractices.com\r\n")
    _T("You can replace this text with your own.\r\n")
    _T("We're using a setup.dll to show this dialog.\r\n")
    _T("Extra line to force vertical scrollbar.\r\n")
    _T("Extra line to force vertical scrollbar.\r\n")
    _T("Extra line to force vertical scrollbar.\r\n")
    _T("Extra line to force vertical scrollbar.\r\n")
    _T("Extra line to force vertical scrollbar.\r\n")
    _T("Extra line to force vertical scrollbar.\r\n")
    _T("Last line.\r\n")
        ;

// This function will be called when the user
// tries to install the cab. According to its return
// value the installation continues or is cancelled.
// As this could be called more than once
// (i.e. if there is not enough space on the target)
// we should take care about fFirstCall parameter
// to show the dialog only once.

codeINSTALL_INIT Install_Init(    HWND        hwndParent,
            BOOL        fFirstCall,
            BOOL        fPreviouslyInstalled,
            LPCTSTR     pszInstallDir )
{
    if (!fFirstCall 
            || 
            ::MessageBoxW(0, Message, 
            _T("SplashScreenSample")
                    , MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
        return codeINSTALL_INIT_CONTINUE;
    else
        return codeINSTALL_INIT_CANCEL;
}
```

So I want to change this to something that can scroll. Can I use like a panel control since I know what has scroll or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably create a DialogBox with the TOS text in a TextBox on it.  That way you can take advantage of the fact that a TextBox automatically can do scrolling.

You'd then use [CreateDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645434(VS.85).aspx) or [DialogBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645452(VS.85).aspx) to do the actual display.

A side bonus here is that you can use the resource editor for basic window layout.

I know you said you don't want to learn C (this is C, not C++) but I really can't envision you doing this without at least some basic understanding of the fundamentals of Win32, like WndPrcs, etc.  Doug Boling's book "[Programming Windows CE](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=6535&locale=en-us)" has some super-simple UI apps in it that use plain Win32, so those would be a decent start.  So would probably any basic tutorial [on DialogBox](http://winprog.org/tutorial/dialogs.html) [or CreateDialog](http://winprog.org/tutorial/modeless_dialogs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of what I called `consoleMessageBox`. It repurposes console as very cool and unique Dialog, that you won't see in any other program, ever. It has fully functional buttons and there is no problems to display ton of text. If you want, you can customise buttons easily.

```
void clip(LPCWSTR txt)
{
    SIZE_T l = wcslen(txt) + 1;
    HGLOBAL hmem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, l * sizeof(wchar_t));
    memcpy(GlobalLock(hmem), txt, l * sizeof(wchar_t));
    GlobalUnlock(hmem);
    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    EmptyClipboard(); // Using this with OpenClipboard(NULL) should not work, but it does! Magick?
    SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hmem);
    CloseClipboard();
}

HANDLE ih;
HANDLE oh;

void pcp(wchar_t c, int n, int x, int y)
{
    COORD p;
    p.X = x;
    p.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(oh, p);
    while(--n >= 0)
    {
        WriteConsoleW(oh, &c, 1, NULL, NULL);
    }
}

void pcc(wchar_t c, int n)
{
    while(--n >= 0)
    {
        WriteConsoleW(oh, &c, 1, NULL, NULL);
    }
}

//_______________
//|             |
//|  TALL BUTT  |
//|_____________|

//| SHORT BUTT |

#define MAX_SCR_W 119
#define MAX_SCR_H 31
#define MIN_SCR_H 15

#define CONBUTT_NUM     3
#define DIST_BTW_BUTTS  2
#define DIST_MAIN_EXTRA 1
#define DIST_EXTRA_TEXT 1
#define BT_TALL_HEIGHT  4
#define BT_SHORT_HEIGHT 1

#define BT_NORM 0x0
#define BT_HOVR 0x1
#define BT_PRST 0x2

#define BT_TALL  0x0
#define BT_SHORT 0x1

SHORT min_scr_w;
SHORT header_h;

typedef struct
{
    SHORT x;
    SHORT y;
    SHORT xt; // x top of collision rectangle
    SHORT yt; // y top
    SHORT xb; // x bottom
    SHORT yb; // y bottom
    LPCWSTR txt;
    int ret; // Return code
    SIZE_T w; // Width
    SHORT st; // Button state
    SHORT sz; // Button size
} CONBUTT;

void pButt(CONBUTT *b)
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO scr_inf;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(oh, &scr_inf);
    WORD def = scr_inf.wAttributes, hlight = def;
    
    if(b->st != BT_NORM)
    {
        hlight = b->st & BT_PRST ? FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_INTENSITY |
            BACKGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE :
            BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE;
    }
    
    int txt_pad = 2, txt_y_offset = 2;
    SIZE_T l = wcslen(b->txt);
    if(b->sz == BT_TALL)
    {
        pcp('_', l + 6, b->x, b->y);
        pcp('|', 1, b->x, b->y+1);
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(oh, hlight);
        pcc(' ', l + 4);
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(oh, def);
        pcc('|', 1);
    }
    else
    {
        txt_pad = 1;
        txt_y_offset = 0;
    }
    
    pcp('|', 1, b->x, b->y + txt_y_offset);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(oh, hlight);
    pcc(' ', txt_pad);
    LPCWSTR t = b->txt - 1;
    while(*(++t) != 0)
    {
        pcc(*t, 1);
    }
    pcc(' ', txt_pad);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(oh, def);
    pcc('|', 1);
    
    if(b->sz == BT_TALL)
    {
        pcp('|', 1, b->x, b->y+3);
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(oh, hlight);
        pcc('_', l + 4);
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(oh, def);
        pcc('|', 1);
    }
}

SIZE_T wButt(LPCWSTR txt, int size) // Button width
{
    SIZE_T l = wcslen(txt);
    int txt_pad = size == BT_TALL ? 2 : 1;
    
    return l + 2 + txt_pad * 2;
}

void calcLines(SIZE_T *max_line, SIZE_T *line, SIZE_T *lines)
{
    *max_line = *line > *max_line ? *line : *max_line;
    if(*line > MAX_SCR_W)
    {
        *lines += *line/MAX_SCR_W;
        *lines += *line % MAX_SCR_W > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ++(*lines);
    }
}

void scrBufSize(LPCWSTR txt, SMALL_RECT *scr, COORD *buf, SIZE_T *len)
{   
    SIZE_T lines = 0;
    SIZE_T line = 0;
    SIZE_T max_line = 0;
    --txt;
    while(*(++txt) != 0)
    {
        ++line;
        ++(*len);
        if(*txt == '\n')
        {
            calcLines(&max_line, &line, &lines);
            line = 0;
        }
    }
    
    if(*(--txt) != '\n') // No terminating newline found
    {
        calcLines(&max_line, &line, &lines);
    }
    
    lines += header_h;
    
    scr->Left = 0;
    scr->Top = 0;
    scr->Right = max_line < min_scr_w ? min_scr_w : max_line > MAX_SCR_W ? MAX_SCR_W : max_line;
    scr->Bottom = lines < MIN_SCR_H ? MIN_SCR_H : lines > MAX_SCR_H ? MAX_SCR_H : lines;
    
    buf->X = scr->Right + 1;
    buf->Y = lines < MIN_SCR_H ? MIN_SCR_H + 1 : lines > 0x7FFF ? 0x7FFF : lines + 1;
}

int consoleMessageBox(LPCWSTR text, LPCWSTR title)
{
    static int ret_val = -1;
    
    // Create main buttons
    static CONBUTT b[CONBUTT_NUM];
    b[0].x = 2;
    b[0].y = 0;
    b[0].txt = L"ABORT";
    b[0].ret = IDABORT;

    b[1].txt = L"RETRY";
    b[1].ret = IDRETRY;

    b[2].txt = L"IGNORE";
    b[2].ret = IDIGNORE;
    
    min_scr_w = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < CONBUTT_NUM; ++i)
    {
        if(i > 0)
        {
            b[i].x = b[i-1].x + b[i-1].w + DIST_BTW_BUTTS;
            b[i].y = b[i-1].y;
        }
        
        b[i].st = BT_NORM;
        b[i].sz = BT_TALL;
        b[i].w = wButt(b[i].txt, b[i].sz);
        b[i].xt = b[i].x;
        b[i].yt = b[i].y;
        b[i].xb = b[i].x + b[i].w;
        b[i].yb = b[i].y + BT_TALL_HEIGHT;
        
        min_scr_w += b[i].w + DIST_BTW_BUTTS;
    }
    min_scr_w += b[0].x;
    --min_scr_w;
    
    header_h = b[0].y + BT_TALL_HEIGHT + DIST_MAIN_EXTRA + BT_SHORT_HEIGHT + DIST_EXTRA_TEXT;
    
    // Create extra buttons
    static CONBUTT clip_b;
    clip_b.txt = L"COPY TO CLIPBOARD";
    clip_b.ret = -1;
    clip_b.st = BT_NORM;
    clip_b.sz = BT_SHORT;
    clip_b.w =  wButt(clip_b.txt, clip_b.sz);
    clip_b.x = clip_b.w < min_scr_w ? (min_scr_w - clip_b.w)/2 : 0;
    clip_b.y = b[0].y + BT_TALL_HEIGHT + DIST_MAIN_EXTRA;
    clip_b.xt = clip_b.x - 1;
    clip_b.yt = clip_b.y - 1;
    clip_b.xb = clip_b.x + clip_b.w;
    clip_b.yb = clip_b.y + BT_SHORT_HEIGHT;
    
    // Adjust console size and buffer
    COORD def_sz, sz;
    SMALL_RECT def_scrsz, scrsz;
    SIZE_T txtl = 0;
    scrBufSize(text, &scrsz, &sz, &txtl);
    
    FreeConsole();
    AllocConsole();
    
    SetConsoleTitleW(title);
    
    ih = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    oh = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(oh, TRUE, &scrsz);
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(oh, sz);
    
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(oh, &csbi);
    def_sz = csbi.dwSize;
    def_scrsz = csbi.srWindow;
    
    // Hide cursor
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO def_cur;
    GetConsoleCursorInfo(oh, &def_cur);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO new_cur;
    new_cur.dwSize = 100;
    new_cur.bVisible = FALSE;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(oh, &new_cur);

    DWORD def_con_mode;
    GetConsoleMode(ih, &def_con_mode);
    SetConsoleMode(ih, ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);
    
    // Display all buttons
    for(int i = 0; i < CONBUTT_NUM; ++i)
    {
        pButt(&b[i]);
    }
    
    pButt(&clip_b);

    // Finally, display the text
    COORD p, z;
    p.X = 0;
    p.Y = b[0].y + header_h;
    z.X = 0;
    z.Y = 0;
    
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(oh, p);
    WriteConsoleW(oh, text, txtl, NULL, NULL);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(oh, z);
    
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(oh, TRUE, &scrsz);
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(oh, sz);
    
    INPUT_RECORD ir[128];
    DWORD nread;
    int lmb_st = BT_HOVR;
    CONBUTT *hov_cb = NULL; // Currently hovered console button
    while(1)
    {
        ReadConsoleInput(ih, ir, 128, &nread);
        for(DWORD i = 0; i < nread; ++i)
        {
            if(ir[i].EventType == MOUSE_EVENT)
            {
                const MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD* m = &ir[i].Event.MouseEvent;
                
                COORD c = m->dwMousePosition;
                int x = c.X;
                int y = c.Y;
                
                // Handle main buttons
                CONBUTT *pb = b - 1;
                CONBUTT *pbe = b + CONBUTT_NUM;
                while(++pb <= pbe && pb != &clip_b)
                {
                    if(pb == pbe) // Sneak in extra button
                    {
                        pb = &clip_b;
                    }
                    
                    if(lmb_st == BT_PRST && pb != hov_cb) // Ignore other buttons if LMB pressed
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    if(x > pb->xt && y > pb->yt
                        && x < pb->xb && y < pb->yb) // Collision detection core
                    {
                        if(!(pb->st & BT_HOVR) || !(pb->st & BT_PRST))
                        {
                            pb->st |= BT_HOVR | lmb_st;
                            pButt(pb);
                            ret_val = pb->ret;
                            hov_cb = pb;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(pb->st & BT_HOVR)
                        {
                            pb->st &= ~(BT_PRST | lmb_st);
                            pButt(pb);
                            ret_val = -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if(m->dwEventFlags == MOUSE_MOVED || hov_cb == NULL)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                
                if(m->dwButtonState & 0x1) // LMB is beeing pressed
                {
                    lmb_st = BT_PRST;
                    
                    if(hov_cb->st & BT_HOVR)
                    {
                        if(!(hov_cb->st & BT_PRST))
                        {
                            hov_cb->st |= BT_PRST;
                            pButt(hov_cb);
                            ret_val = hov_cb->ret;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(!(m->dwButtonState & 0x1)) // LMB was released
                {
                    lmb_st = BT_HOVR;
                    
                    if(hov_cb->st & BT_HOVR)
                    {
                        if(ret_val > 0)
                        {
                            goto exit;
                        }
                        else // Only one special button, no need to check which one
                        {
                            clip(text);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if(hov_cb->st & BT_PRST)
                    {
                        hov_cb->st &= ~BT_PRST;
                        pButt(hov_cb);
                        ret_val = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
exit:
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(oh, &def_cur);
    SetConsoleMode(ih, def_con_mode);
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(oh, TRUE, &def_scrsz);
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(oh, def_sz);
    FreeConsole();
    return ret_val;
}
```